# Unable to load servlet on button submit action in JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I have simple `login.jsp` page as:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/SchoolERP/Login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="control-label col-sm-1">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-1">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My `web.xml` file contain following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SchoolERP</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SchoolERP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rms.school.controllers.ControllerHome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SchoolERP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SchoolERP</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rms.school.controllers.ControllerLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SchoolERP/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <!-- This welcome filename is linked to above mentioned url-pattern -->
    <welcome-file>SchoolERP</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Where `ControllerLogin.java` is as follows:

```
public class ControllerLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/template.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("content_page", "admin/login.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("title", "Login");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I click on submit button on Login.jsp page, it's giving error as `requested resource  /SchoolERP/Login  not found`. Where am I doing wrong?

I tried various variations like `action="Login"` in login.jsp. Also in `web.xml` I tried using `Login`, `/SchoolERP/Login`, etc. But still error is there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. I removed `Login` `<servlet>` definition from `web.xml` and added annotation to `ControllerLogin` servlet as `@WebServlet({"/Login"})`. And this worked. But I'm still unable to understand where is above code getting wrong?